# Deploy a React-based single-page application to Amazon S3 and CloudFront - Access Denied

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I tried using Amazon's instructions step by step in this article:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/deploy-a-react-based-single-page-application-to-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront.html

Perhaps this article is outdated, incomplete or I have misunderstood something. I have done everything step-by-step on my free tier, and have verified and retried several times.

I checked to see that CloudFormation created all the infrastructure and I  uploaded all the files and folders correctly to S3.

Upon finishing, when I use the URL created by Cloudfront, I encounter an 'Access-denied' message, similar to:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>{{id}}</RequestId>
<HostId>{{id}}</HostId>
</Error>
```

Perhaps there are additional steps required in addition to the documentation, but they make it appear as though following the steps is sufficient.

If you have some experience and can help me out, I'd be very grateful.

I have tried the article's instructions step-by-step

I have tried removing the 'block' on the S3 bucket to ensure public access is allowed, even though it is not mentioned in the tutorial

Comment: Sounds like your CloudFront distribution does not have proper access to the objects in your S3 bucket, so start checking there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of following that older one, there is a newer applicable example that will walk you through building a React app that does deploy the React app to CloudFront. I recommend working through this example to gain a deeper understanding of this use case.

This example is in the [AWS Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html).

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_cross_PAM_section.html)